# Will a NAS server be adequate for this intended usage?

Tags: storage, network-attached-storage

I'm looking to get a small server to predominantly act as a content storage network drive but I will also want to be able to run Ubuntu or even just the most basic Linux distro. It will have XAMPP and WAMPP stacks configured on it but the bulk of usage will be copying / reading of content over the network and local web development and pushing sites to live environments.

Am I right in thinking that a NAS server would be adequate for what we really intend to do use it for? I don't think in this instance anything more would be needed would it?

Would something such as this [NETGEAR ReadyNAS 102](https://www.google.co.uk/shopping/product/4616342115011625591?q=small%20office%20servers&biw=1280&bih=963&sa=X&ei=gxqkU5D3Fey10QXC74CgCQ&ved=0COsCEPMCMBE4UA) be suitable?

Comment: I would think a small NAS would be okay for this but it would be almost impossible to make any confident assessment since every group of web developers has different requirements and usage profile.

Comment: Oh sure, I appreciate that and I wasn't intending for any further recommendation beyond the basics of my question really. Having not purchased any NAS servers before, I just wanted to clarify that for any usage along the lines of what we required, it would be suitable for. Thanks.

Comment: do you know how much storage you require?

Comment: It needs to be scalable ideally but starting from 2TB or thereabouts.

Comment: Just realized you wanted to actually run Linux on the NAS. I assumed you meant run a Linux server on some other hardware that is connected to the NAS. My mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

A NAS is a specialized appliance with a vendor-supplied firmware. It is not a general-purpose server.

Of course, since most NAS appliances are coming with off-the-shelf hardware nowadays, you should be able to hack a NAS appliance into a simple Linux install, but you obviously will lose all support from the vendor. It also typically is not worth the effort as you can buy [small but more powerful general-purpose machines for about the same amount of money](https://www.google.co.uk/search?biw=1280&bih=963&output=search&tbm=shop&q=microserver&oq=microserver).

If it is just about using it as a piece of storage, then just go straight on. But do not forget to read the reviews beforehand - many low-end appliances are rather poorly equipped and underpowered so they probably would not deliver the performance you're hoping for.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for this advice - it's exactly what I needed to know and your suggested microservers will give me something to go on now that will suit our requirements.

Comment: @zigojacko - don't forget to come back and mark this as the accepted answer.